# Assertion failed when I want to use calcHist to generate the number of pixels in a specific range of a picture

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv

I want to calculate the number of pixels in a specific range of color using calcHist. However I get following errors:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (dims <= 2 && data && (unsigned)i0 < (unsigned)(size.p[0]*size.p[1]) && elemSize() == (((((DataType<_Tp>::type) & ((512 - 1) << 3)) >> 3) + 1) << ((((sizeof(size_t)/4+1)*16384|0x3a50) >> ((DataType<_Tp>::type) & ((1 << 3) - 1))*2) & 3))) in cv::Mat::at, file e:\opencv2.4\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\mat.hpp, line 570

ZKB_shop.exe has triggered a breakpoint.
```

My code shows like followings:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, const char** argv) {
    Mat image = imread("D:\\obj\\138.jpg");
    Mat img_hsv;
    cvtColor(image, img_hsv, CV_BGR2HSV);

    int hbins = 1;
    int sbins = 1;
    int vbins = 1;
    int histSize[] = { hbins,sbins,vbins };

    //H
    float hranges[] = { 0,20 };
    //S
    float sranges[] = { 100,255 };
    //V
    float vranges[] = { 107,245 };
    const float* ranges[] = { hranges,sranges,vranges };

    MatND hist;
    //chanels
    int channels[] = { 0,1,2 };

    calcHist(&img_hsv, 1, channels, Mat(), hist, 3, histSize, ranges);
    cout << "Hist.dims = " << hist.dims << endl;
    cout << "Value: " << hist.at<double>(0) << endl;
    cout << "Hist.rows = " << hist.rows << endl;
    cout << "Hist.cols = " << hist.cols << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I adapt the code from the official tutorial :http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d6/dc7/group__imgproc__hist.html#ga4b2b5fd75503ff9e6844cc4dcdaed35d
and add one more channel but I have no idea why it doesn't work.

I use VS2015+WIN10+OPENCV2.4.11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're over-complicating this.

To get the number of pixels in a given color range, you can:

1. Create a mask of values in the given color range, using `inRange`
2. Count the number of non-zero pixels in the mask, with `countNonZero`

Code:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // Read the image
    Mat image = imread("path_to_image");
    // Convert to HSV
    Mat img_hsv;
    cvtColor(image, img_hsv, CV_BGR2HSV);

    // Define lower and upper ranges
    Scalar lower(0, 100, 107);
    Scalar upper(20, 255, 245);

    // Create a mask with pixels in range
    Mat1b mask;
    inRange(img_hsv, lower, upper, mask);

    // Count the number of non-black pixels
    int cnz = countNonZero(mask);

    cout << "# pixels in range " << cnz << endl;

    return 0;
}
```